# CSS Layout with a container and two sidebars

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: Layout]

I've tried to achieve this layout with CSS, however, the sidebars (in red) expand whenever there is content in them. I would like if the sidebars maintained a constant width regardless of the content inside of them.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex-basis` is the way.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 1024px;
}

.sidebar {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: calc((100vw - 1024px)/2);
}
```

Replacing `1024px` with whatever you desire the container width to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) CSS property to set the width of each section as the code below:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 70%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 15%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>css flex</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="sidebar">side-left Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid dicta facere fuga harum incidunt maiores molestiae necessitatibus nihil, nisi obcaecati odio odit quis quisquam rem reprehenderit totam vel voluptatibus?</section>

  <section class="container">container Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi debitis deserunt dolore eius enim eum exercitationem explicabo, fuga iusto nam nesciunt nostrum obcaecati odio odit quas rem sapiente suscipit tempora tenetur velit. Accusantium aliquam dignissimos ea eos laboriosam molestiae nemo nobis optio pariatur, rerum tenetur.</section>

  <section class="sidebar">side-right Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab assumenda consectetur dignissimos eos et hic in ipsa ipsum nam officiis perferendis qui, quisquam recusandae, repellendus, repudiandae rerum tempore. Asperiores at atque consectetur cum, deleniti deserunt dolorum error exercitationem fuga harum illum ipsam nisi nostrum omnis placeat provident, quaerat, qui quos sed sequi temporibus velit voluptatum?</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used this for my answer but without the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a basic CSS layout with a container element and two sidebars:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    <!-- sidebar content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <!-- main content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
    <!-- sidebar content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

````
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-left {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.main-content {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}```
````